# Simple XML HELP !

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need some help ,

All I need to do is change "HERE" to a the value of $date

```
$line1 = $sxe->addChild("date","HERE");
```

How can I add the value of $date into the area were "HERE" is ?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sxe->addChild("date", $date);
```

Comment: just changed it too $sxe->addChild('date', $date);

and it works :) 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Actually the following wont work unless the `date` node exists. Listen to the others... We see how often i actually modify structure with SimpleXml ;-)

`$sxe->date = $date;`